# Maven fail-safe not executing tests

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've combed StackOverflow and many other sites, have found many other related posts and have followed all said suggestions, but in the end, **failsafe is skipping my tests.**

My JUnit test is located here:
`myModule/src/main/test/java/ClientAccessIT.java`

I am **skipping surefire** because there are no unit tests in this module:

```
<!-- POM snippet -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And I'm trying to run integration tests with **failsafe**:

```
<!-- POM snippet -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>run-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, when I run `mvn verify` I see this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14.1:integration-test (run-tests) @ rest-services-test ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I spent the last 4 1/2 hours scouring, any help would be appreciated. The only other thing that may be worth mentioning is that I have [Cargo](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html) setting up and tearing down a Tomcat container. Does anybody see the glaring problem?

Comment: Why isn't `maven-failsafe-plugin` running out of the box on the `integration-test` phase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to rename your test class.

You can find the names the plugin looks for by default in [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), as pointed out by @acdcjunior:

> By default, the Failsafe Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - "`**/IT*.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "IT".
> - "`**/*IT.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "IT".
> - "`**/*ITCase.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "ITCase".

Comment: That does not seem to be true: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html - it says the default patterns are `**/IT*.java`, `**/*IT.java`, `**/*ITCase.java`.

Comment: @acdcjunior beat me to it; here's a direct link to the relevant documentation page: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes

Comment: "**/*IT.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "IT". Wouldn't ClientAccessIT.java meet the qualifications of this pattern?

Comment: The example "ClientAccessIT.java" clearly matches *IT.java. So this answer is just useless and confusing.

Comment: if you are usin JUnit 5 you can include them by filtering and using tags: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading. The correct answer was given by @pro-tester

Answer (score 29):

Your tests are not in the default test sources directory src/test/java. See:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

myModule/src/main/test/java/ClientAccessIT.java

should be:

myModule/src/test/java/ClientAccessIT.java

You could also update your pom file (if you really wanted tests to live in main) to include:

```
<build>
    <testSources>
        <testSource>
            <directory>src/main/test</directory>
        </testSource>
    </testSources>
</build>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The given example clearly doesn't work because of this.

Comment: Did you mean `<testResources>` or `<testSourceDirectory>`? I cannot find element `<testSources`>

Comment: This has changed. Since failsafe v2.2.: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testSourceDirectory

Answer (score 23):

If you happen to use **Spring Boot version 2.4** or higher, and your tests still use **JUnit 4**, remember to put this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Version 2.4 of `spring-boot-starter-test` includes only JUnit 5 and removed the vintage engine that provided a TestEngine for running JUnit 3 and 4 based tests.

Without that vintage engine, all JUnit 4 tests are silently ignored.

Comment: Thanks neXus for this answer. It saved lot of time, since it was very difficult to find the cause, as no test where executed for me as all of the test where written in Junit4.

Comment: Or update to junit 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073944/it-are-no-longer-executed-with-failsafe-plugin-after-migrating-to-spring-boot-2/70991122#70991122 :)

Comment: This was my issue.  Some how whoever set up our integration tests got them on an old version of jUnit, while the unit tests were on jUnit 5 and worked just fine.  So my mvn verify would execute unit test but int test would have 0 test found.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem. If there aren't any test classes compiled to target/test-classes then check your pom file and ensure that the packaging isn't 'pom'.

Comment: What is "packaging isn't pom"?  Any hint?

Comment: Look in your effective pom.xml for the tag "packaging". Look at this link for a bit more about the packaging tag. https://maven.apache.org/pom.html. the key is to ensure that the value of that tag is not "pom".

Answer (score 18):

For multi-module projects, the child project needs to have the plugin declared as followed,

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
 </plugin>
```

version inherits from parent pom. Without the above defined, the plugin in parent pom alone will not work.

Comment: I had to define plugin inside parent's pom (pluginManagement section) and use it on the project's pom (plugins section)

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same issue and tried a few of the suggested options here. I am developing a Spring Boot application using JUnit 5. Unfortunately, none of my integration tests (located in `src/test/java` and suffixed with `*TestIT.java`) were getting picked up, regardless of the [advertising of the plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html#) to do so. I tried [downgrading to 2.18.1 and 2.19.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254) and tried both removing the `<executions>` and `<configuration>` sections to attempt to use even the plugin's default functionality, but no luck.

I finally changed the version to the latest (as of the time of writing) to 2.22.0, and viola. Here is the configuration I added to the `<build><plugins>` section of my pom. And even better, I don't need to add executions that define the `integration-test` and `verify` goals that you see most people include; failsafe executes these by default. I've included my surefire plugin configuration as well, since I am using it to execute unit tests during the `test` phase of the maven lifecycle.

**Edit:** I also had to ad the `integration-test` and `verify` executions to the plugin configuration as well.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And just for good measure, to tell surefire and failsafe [to use JUnit 5](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html), I am including this in my `<dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Eclipse displays a warning (yellow squiggly underline) under the version tag, hence the inclusion of the `<!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->` error. I'm sure there's a better way to deal with this, but it works for me in this case.

To speed up testing this configuration, and to avoid having to go through **all** of the earlier lifecycle phases before `test`, `integration-test` or`verify` phases, I used the following commands to quickly validate:

- `mvn failsafe:integration-test` (runs only integration tests)
- `mvn surefire:test` (runs only unit tests)
- (I obviously run the entire lifecycle when it counts)

Hope this helps someone. Cheers!

Comment: For me nothing was working without this junit-jupiter-engine dependency added in tests module. Thanks for the hint! Although I don't fully understand yet how it actually influenced it and made it work... Can anyone explain? When I started these tests by surfire-plugin (in default test phase), then the dependency wasn't needed and everything worked.

Comment: See the comment from Horatiu.
He has the right solution, as by the Maven references:

                 <goal>integration-test</goal>
 and
                <goal>verify</goal>

Comment: Interesting. I used to have to downgrade to 2.18.1. Which still works for me.  Unless your tests are junit 5 then I have to use M-3.0.x https://stackoverflow.com/a/70991122/32453

Answer (score 6):

I also had a similar problem but needed the packaging element to be "pom". Make sure your test source files are being compiled and added to the .../target/test-classes folder using the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Strangely my packaging was jar but test classes were not compiled. Thanks.

Comment: This was my issue also, as soon as I included compiler plugin integration tests started working!

Comment: My packaging was also jar and I also need to do this

Answer (score 5):

For me it was a missing executions section

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

The failsafe with TestNG documentation at
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/testng.html
 had shown a pom without it, and it didn't work.

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

Adding the missing executions section shown above solved the problem.

Comment: Of course we do not write all such details in the documenttaion because the specification related to the plugin goals are phase are related to the basic understanding of the Maven and plugin documentation and Maven basics. See the goals https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/plugin-info.html, what defaul phase (acctualy failsafe does not have default phase but surefire has it) and then we expect that the user has a common understanding of these things. I would recommend separating the goal *integration-test* and *verify* under separate execution *id*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using java 8, failsafe plugin version 2.22.2 => tests not running problem, to solve this I added next:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
             <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
             <version>2.22.2</version>
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>integration</id>
             <phase>integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The goals **integration-test** and **verify** have to be listed in the execution(s) section of the plugin. Otherwise you won't see it running.

Comment: I added also the execution part.

Comment: I am highly recommending to use one version ${surefire.plugin.version} and not hardcoded version 2.22.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat similar issue. My Integration tests were not being picked up. My project is a multi module spring boot project. And my mistake was that I added maven-failsafe-plugin in the parent POM. After fiddling around with many options I placed the failsafe-plugin in the module pom where all my integration tests were present which solved my problem.

Comment: The goals **integration-test** and **verify** have to be listed in the execution(s) section of the plugin. Otherwise you won't see it running. The place: parent or child was not the answer why you made it running.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `surefire:verify` did not run any tests.
I had to use `surefire:integration-test`.

Comment: Of course it won't work because **surefire** does not have the goals **verify** and **integration-test**, see the documentation https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: If you want to use these goals, you have to use **failsafe** plugin, and the commands will be in this order **mvn failsafe:integration-test** and **mvn failsafe:verify**, see the goals for failsafe in documentation https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/plugin-info.html

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many pieces that can lead to this problem, I will share how mine was resolved.

There was an active profile in my maven settings file ( `.m2/settings.xml` ), it had `maven.test.skip` property set to `true` and that was skipping the tests when I run the tests via maven. It was needed for an old application and I totally forgot about that profile.

```
</profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>god-damnit-profile</id>
      <properties>
        ...
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>god-damnit-profile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

I commented it out and it works now.

```
<activeProfiles>
    <!-- <activeProfile>god-damnit-profile</activeProfile> -->     
</activeProfiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JUnit5`, don't forget to add the following dependency to your test classpath:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```