# Maven failsafe recognizes integration test class but not tests in class

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven project and I'm trying to setup integration testing tooling with the failsafe plugin.

I added the following to the project's parent pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>failsafe</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I also added that exact same snippet to the child module's pom.xml where the initial tests were added along with this snippet:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the directory structure of the module where the initial integration test has been added:

```
parent
-aws-service-utils
--src
---main
----java
-----com
------lorem
-------ipsum
--------S3
---------S3.java (dummy class)
---test (in same directory as main)
----java
-----com
------lorem
-------ipsum
--------dolor
---------tests
----------S3IT.java (test class for dummy class)
```

Here's what `S3.java` looks like, excluding the imported packages:

```
public class S3 {
   public int confirmAdd() {
      int sum = 2 + 2;
      return sum;
   }
}
```

Here's what `S3IT.java` looks like, again excluding imported packages:

```
public class S3IT {
  @Test
  public void confirmAdd() {
     int sum = 2+2;
     assertTrue(sum == 4);
  }
}
```

I run `mvn verify -Pfailsafe` followed by `mvn failsafe:integration-test` and get no test output for all of the other classes, as expected. Then the following comes up for the `aws-service-utils` module:

[image]

So it appears to be recognizing the integration test class S3IT.java but not the test inside. I went through the proposed solutions in a [similar Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387679/maven-fail-safe-not-executing-tests) and none of them worked. My primary resource for setting up integration tests with Maven can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-integration-test).

Comment: Are you using junit or jupiter-api?

Comment: For this project some unit test coverage has already been implemented using JUnit. jupiter-api is not involved in the project.

Comment: Did you tried to include <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java </include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>

Comment: it's a long shoot, but check that your  annotation is the right one: org.junit.Test.

Comment: Try `mvn integration-test` , skip the failsafe prefix, looks like it's taking a different version (3.0.0-M3)